# How can I use Expression tree on arrays?

Tags: c#, .net, expression-trees

I've an input string and I want to convert to an expression tree after that I want return as *Func<int, bool>*, I don't really know how does it work on arrays or lists.

```
    //List<int> numbers = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    static Func<int, bool> Test(string path, string listOrArray, string input) //its gonna be dynamic type later
    {
        // x => (numbers[x] % 2 != 0) && (numbers[x] % 3 != 0);   <-- I wanna return this
        // x => (numbers[x] % 2 != 0);                            <-- or this

        var type = Expression.Parameter(Type.GetType(path)); 
        var prop = Expression.PropertyOrField(type, listOrArray);

        var a = Expression.Constant(3);
        var b = Expression.Constant(2);
        var c = Expression.Constant(0);

        //var temp = Expression<Func<int, bool>> smth;
        //return temp.Compile();
    }
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you intend to use parameters for (in relation to the expression)?

Comment: path <--> Namespace + class     
listOrArray <--> name of array or list    
input <--> expression e.g:::  x => (numbers[x] % 2 != 0)

Comment: Can you give some example inputs and outputs? It's not clear what `path`, `listOrArray` or `input` might contain, or how they might be used

Comment: `namespace SomeThing
{
 class Program
    {
        public List<int> numbers = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var a = Test("SomeThing.Program", "numbers", "x=>numbers[x]%2=!0");
            var b = Test("SomeThing.Program", "numbers", "x => (numbers[x] % 2 != 0) && (numbers[x] % 3 != 0)");
            var c = Test("SomeThing.Program", "numbers", "x=>numbers[x] - 1 == 9");

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
 }
}`

Comment: So you want to instantiate a new instance of SomeThing.Program, access the numbers field, parse that string containing an expression, and... Then what? How do you put the list of numbers and the expression together in a way which produces a `Func<int, bool>`?

Comment: `//var temp = Expression<Func<int, bool>> smth;`
`//return temp.Compile();`

It's return as exactly as I want

Comment: I still don't know how you want to combine all those parts to get a `Func<int, bool>` I'm afraid. I don't think your question can be answered in its current form. Please read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time researching your problem, and here is the solution I found, using numbers.Select():

```
using System.Linq.Expressions;

List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    numbers.Add(i);

Expression<Func<int, bool>> myfunc = num => num % 2 != 0;
Func<int, bool> myfunc2 = myfunc.Compile();

List<bool> computed = numbers.Select(myfunc2).ToList();

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Console.Out.WriteLine("Num: " + numbers[i] + " | Computed: " + computed[i]);
}
```

The computed list contains the output of the lambda function for each value

Output:

```
Num: 0 | Computed: False
Num: 1 | Computed: True
Num: 2 | Computed: False
Num: 3 | Computed: True
Num: 4 | Computed: False
Num: 5 | Computed: True
Num: 6 | Computed: False
Num: 7 | Computed: True
Num: 8 | Computed: False
Num: 9 | Computed: True
```

[Expression Trees Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/#compiling-expression-trees) [Select() Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-6.0)

Comment: Well, this is not exactly what I want. What I want is similar to dynamic lambda expression. Test method get a string expression e.g. "x=>numbers[x]%2=!0" and the expression tree call other methods e.g: Expression.Divide, Expression.Equal and Expression.Constant or smth like that. I dunno 'cuz I never used Array or List in Expression tree. [link](https://www.codemag.com/article/1609041) <---  smth like this

Comment: I am not certain that you can expose method variables in your method to a dynamic lambda expression. I have not used dynamic lambda functions before though, so can't speak much to that effect. 

The link you gave me results in a 500 error

Comment: Why would you need to reference numbers[x] versus just allowing the .Select() to process the Expression? You can still write your lambda function, knowing that instead of directly referencing numbers[x], the value passed to your lambda function (num) is equivalent to numbers[x], and then use the output